# Testing codepaths for older OS versions

Tags: swift, unit-testing, code-coverage

If I have some library with methods like:

```
public struct Foo {
  @available(macOS 10.15, *)
  func greatNewFeature() -> String {
    return "new feature"
  }

  func legacyFeature() -> String {
    return "legacy feature"
  }
}
```

Then some code that uses it:

```
func methodToTest() -> String {
  let foo = Foo()
  guard #available(macOS 10.15, *) else {
    return foo.legacyFeature()
  }
  return foo.greatNewFeature()
}
```

Is there a way I can write unit tests which give me complete coverage of `methodToTest`?

All ideas I have had so far, have not been helpful:

- you can't treat the availability check as injected functionality - the compiler specifically needs the `@available` keyword in order to use the `greatNewFeature` method.
- you can't add some hacky boolean which you could set in the tests like `#available(macOS 10.15, *) || isMacOS10_15` for a similar reason to the previous point.

The only thing I think would work is to run the test suite multiple times - once for each supported OS version, then create a script to combine the code coverage stats. Can anyone think of a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a flag in your tests whether to skip the OS version check or not and `&&` that with your `#available` check.

This way you simply need to call `testFooFeature` with the flag both turned on and off and you'll be able to test both code paths on `macOS 10.15`.

```
var forceOldOSVersion = true

func testFooFeature() -> String {
    let foo = Foo()
    if !forceOldOSVersion, #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
        return foo.greatNewFeature()
    } else {
        return foo.legacyFeature()
    }
}

testFooFeature() // "legacy feature"
```